# Unhandled type to empty string not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an `isEmpty` function that will verify any value and return it to empty string if value is null or undefined.

My below function for some reason is not working and value still comes out as unhandled. When I do straight up `typeof`, it seems to be working fine. Is there anything I am missing?

```js
const isEmpty = value => {
  value === undefined ||
    typeof value === "undefined" ||
    value === null ||
    (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
    (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);
};

  const data = {};
  data.handle = !isEmpty(data.handle) ? data.handle : "";
  console.log("data.handle is still undefined: " + typeof data.handle);

 if (typeof data.handle === "undefined") {
 data.handle = "";
 console.log("empty string yes!!!");
   }
```

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything...

Comment: Thank you! That's a lot of help and good to know. I am still trying to get familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

[**MDN - Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. **In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.**

Because you've wrapped your method in curly brackets, it is considered *block body*.

Either add a `return` before it, or easier yet, make it a concise body by removing the curly brackets:

```js
const isEmpty = value =>
  value === undefined ||
  typeof value === "undefined" ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);

const data = {};
data.handle = !isEmpty(data.handle) ? data.handle : "";
console.log("data.handle is still undefined: " + typeof data.handle);

if (typeof data.handle === "undefined") {
  data.handle = "";
  console.log("empty string yes!!!");
}
```

Comment: Meta note: Although the fix was quite simple, I've chosen not to mark this as "simple typographical error". I feel that the actual explanation behind *why* that simply fix is necessary warranted a deeper explanation, and was not a "typo".

Comment: Definitely not a typo but it was me being newbie of the javascript syntax. The link you attached is going to be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing your `return` statement, thus your `function` returns `undefined`

```js
const isEmpty = value => {
  //you are not returning anything
  return value === undefined ||
    typeof value === "undefined" ||
    value === null ||
    (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
    (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);
};

const data = {};
data.handle = !isEmpty(data.handle) ? data.handle : "";
console.log("data.handle is still undefined: " + typeof data.handle);

if (typeof data.handle === "undefined") {
  data.handle = "";
  console.log("empty string yes!!!");
}
```